# Quat. Quine + Cat

Tags: code-golf, quine

A Quat is a combination of a [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) and the popular esolang [cat](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Cat_program) program.

## Challenge

The challenge is to write a standard cat program. Whatever the user inputs, the program will echo the input to stdout.
However, when the length of the input is greater than 0 **and** a multiple of 4, the program should output its own source code. *Quat* comes from the Portuguese [quatro](https://translate.google.com/#pt/en/quatro), which translates to 'four'.

## Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply
- You may not read the source code from a file
- An empty input should produce an empty output

## Bonus

If your input length is a multiple of 4 you can earn a 25% bonus by printing the quine `length/4` times. Another 5% bonus if you seperate the output by spaces (no trailing space allowed).

## Test cases

The following test cases apply for the program `in%4=0?cat:self` (not a real language).

`<empty input> -> <empty output>`
`input -> input`
`1234 -> in%4=0?cat:self`
`12345678 -> in%4=0?cat:self` **0%** bonus
`12345678 -> in%4=0?cat:selfin%4=0?cat:self` **25%** bonus
`12345678 -> in%4=0?cat:self in%4=0?cat:self` **30%** bonus

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Can the input have multiple lines?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Ofcourse, let `\n` be the new line character, for 1 byte of input

Comment: Okay, it just complicates input in my language, which must be read one line at a time.

Comment: Are built-ins for quines allowed? (see: [Seriously](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66310/44713))

Comment: @FlagAsSpam I don't mind, but I think a meta-post is more appropriate here.

Comment: @Bas I meant for _your question_, not in general. But okie den.

Comment: @FlagAsSpam The OP of [What counts as a proper quine?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4877/31388) says "Clearly, any quine in HQ9+ or a related language is not a proper quine," and I don't see any contention over that point in the answers. I'm pretty sure I've seen that same point made in other posts.

Comment: Is there any maximum input size we have to support? (I.e. do we have to buffer all 5 gigabytes of input until deciding whether to output them or the own source code?)

Answer (score 8):

### CJam, 23 * 0.75 = 17.25 bytes

Standard generalised quine...

```
{`"_~"+q:Q,4md@@*Q\?}_~
```

or

```
{`"_~"+q_,4md@@]:\*?}_~
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B%60%22_~%22%2Bq%3AQ%2C4md%40%40*Q%5C%3F%7D_~&input=12345678)

#### Explanation

```
{`"_~"+  e# Generalised quine framework. Leaves the source code on the stack.
  q:Q    e# Read input and store it in Q.
  ,      e# Get its length.
  4md    e# Divmod 4.
  @      e# Pull up the source code.
  @      e# Pull up the div.
  *      e# Repeat the source code that many times.
  Q\     e# Push the input and swap it below the repeated source.
  ?      e# Pick the right output based on the modulo.
}_~
```

The other version avoids the use of a variable by using the stack-rotation trick `]:\`.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 33 * .75 = 24.75

```
?%lz4z*/lz4jN*2]"?%lz4z*/lz4jN*2]
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3F%25lz4z%2A%2Flz4jN%2A2%5D%22%3F%25lz4z%2A%2Flz4jN%2A2%5D&input=asdf&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%0A1%0A12%0A123%0A1234%0A12345%0A12345678%0A123456781234&debug=0)

Standard Pyth quine using join. This is only a true quine on the online interpreter, which doesn't add a final trailing newline.

Getting the final bonus reults in a score of 39 * .7 = 27.3:

```
?%lz4zjd*/lz4]jN*2]"?%lz4zjd*/lz4]jN*2]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Emacs Lisp (323 * 0.75 = 242.25)

```
((lambda (s) (let* ((a (read-string "")) (l (string-bytes a))) (if (> (% l 4) 0) (message a) (dotimes (v (/ l 4)) (prin1 (list s (list (quote quote) s))))))) (quote (lambda (s) (let* ((a (read-string "")) (l (string-bytes a))) (if (> (% l 4) 0) (message a) (dotimes (v (/ l 4)) (prin1 (list s (list (quote quote) s)))))))))
```

This uses Lisp's quoting mechanic to give the source code as input to itself.

**Old cheating version**

```
:; exec emacs -Q -script $0
(find-file(nth 2 command-line-args))(set'b(buffer-string))(set's(read-string""))(set'l(string-bytes s))(if(>(% l 4)0)(message s)(dotimes(v(/ l 4))(message"%s"b)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
:; exec emacs -Q -script $0
(find-file(nth 2 command-line-args)) ; open self
(set'b(buffer-string))               ; read own code to string
(set's(read-string""))               ; read input
(set'l(string-bytes s))              ; length of input
(if(>(% l 4)0)                       ; l % 4 > 0 ?
    (message s)                      ; output input
  (dotimes(v(/ l 4))                 ; (implicit else) repeat l/4 times
    (message"%s"b)))                 ; output own code
```

Comment: Doesn't this violate the rule that "You may not read the source code from a file"?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot you're right... guess I'll have to look for a non-cheating Quine in Elisp

Answer (score 2):

### Seriously, <s>8</s> 9 bytes

```
Q,ó;l4@%I
```

[Try it Online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=512ca23b6c34402549&input=hello,%20y%60all)

(Hit enter once in the input box to test empty input.)

The first bonus can be done in 12 bytes (16*.75):

```
Q,ó;l;4@\(*)4@%I
```

Explanation:

```
Q                   Push program source to stack
 ,ó                 Push input string, and terminate if it's empty
   ;l               Push length of input
     4@%            Take the length mod 4.
        I           Pick the next stack element (input) if nonzero,
                    else the next next (program source)
```

Since some people don't like the use of Seriously's quining built-in, I provide this 22 byte version that doesn't use `Q` for reference:

```
`è";ƒ"(+,ó;l4@%I`;ƒ
```

If you are one of those people, consider this the definitive version (for now) and then go start a meta thread about the use of built-ins in quines.

Comment: In a [tag:quine] challenge, I believe you cannot read the program source.

Comment: The instructions say you cannot read it from a file. Q is a built-in command that pushes the source to the stack when it is empty. I think this falls under "playing to the language's strengths"

Comment: I think a built-in quining function does read the source code. That's like using a built-in for a binomial coefficient challenge, when the challenge says "no built-in factorials".

Comment: It doesn't say "don't use quining built-ins"... And not using built-ins is not an accepted standard loophole

Comment: Q does not read the program's source from a file, technically - it's in RAM, stored by the interpreter. Since the rule specifically states "from a file", this should be valid.

Comment: I don't really understand why this is more popular than any previous languages with built-in quine operators, including HQ9+ and Ismael's MarioGolf. But in any case your program doesn't seem to work correctly for empty input.

Comment: Hmm. I think when I tested empty input in the REPL, it actually gave it a newline, so it looked empty... Or something like that.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Seriously is a valid programming language by our definition, unlike HQ9+. I don't know why Mario Golf isn't more popular; I think it's neat. The main difference I can see is that `Q` isn't *just* a built-in one-byte quine; it's also the simplest way to do recursion in functions.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

<s>*So close*.</s> Yus. I am now winning amongst non-built in quiners! *glares at Seriously*

```
zl4M([&'rd3*8\}]Z
z                 Grab ALL THE INPUT! :D
 l4M([         ]  If the input is a multiple of four, do the stuff in brackets.
      &           Generate a new stack and move to it.
       'rd3*      Standard quine.
            8\}   Push the bottom 8 items of the stack to the top.
                Z Output the current stack.
```

There's no reason for me to go after the bonuses - they'd chuck on a lot more bytes.

### Cheating quine version, 12 bytes:

```
zl4M([&iG`]Z
zl4M([&   ]Z  Same as above.
       i      Push -1.
        G     Get the name of the file with this index of use (-1 is self)
         `    Read the file with the given name and push its contents to the stack.
```

Comment: ``G` `` is cool! It seems more legit than a simple `Q` command.

Comment: Seems less legit to me, seeing as how it requires file I/O.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Quintopia is right - just because I get the file reference doesn't mean it's any better. :P

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>68</s> 65 * 0.75 = 48.75 bytes

```
perl -e'$_=q{print+($l=($~=<>)=~y///c)%4?$~:"\$_=q{$_};eval"x($l/4)};eval'
```

See the online test suite [here.](http://ideone.com/lgZwPo)

### Broken down

```
perl -e'
    $_=q{                      # store source code in $_
        print+(
            $l=($~=<>)=~ y///c # read STDIN into $~, assign length to $l
        )%4 ?                  # if length is a multiple of 4
             $~ :              # print $~
             "\$_=q{$_};eval"  # otherwise, print source code
             x($l/4)           # length/4 times
    };
    eval'                      # eval $_ to execute its contents
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>57</s> <s>56</s> 72 bytes * 0.75 = 54

Thanks to @Neil for a one byte savings!

```
(f=_=>alert(!(p=prompt())||(l=p.length)%4?p:`(f=${f})()`.repeat(l/4)))()
```

The shortest solution I could find was pretty straight-forward.

So, here's a couple bonus (more interesting) solutions:

#### JavaScript, <s>82</s> 81 bytes * 0.75 = 60.75

```
f=_=>{try{p=prompt();a=`f=${f};f()`.repeat(p.length/4)}catch(e){a=p}alert(a)};f()
```

This one abuses `repeat`'s functionality of throwing an exception if passed a non-integer.

#### JavaScript, 83 bytes * 0.70 = 58.1

```
(f=_=>alert((a=(p=prompt()).split(/.{4}/)).pop()?p:a.fill(`(f=${f})()`).join` `))()
```

This last one is definitely my favorite, splitting the input on every four characters using the regex `/.{4}/`. If there are any characters left at the end of the string when we `pop`, it isn't divisible by 4, so alert the input. Otherwise, the `pop` reduced the array's length by one, so at this point the array's length is equal to the input length / 4. In this case, just `fill` it with the quine and `join` with spaces.

Comment: I think you can save a byte by inverting the condition; change the `&&` to `||`, put a `!` before the `(p=prompt())`, remove the `<1` and move the `p` to be on the inside of the `?:`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 71 bytes -30% = 49.7

```python
exec(a:="s=len(t:=input());print(*s%4and[t]or s//4*['exec(a:=%r)'%a])")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7UiNVkj0cpWqdg2JzVPo8TKNjOvoLREQ1PTuqAoM69EQ6tY1SQxLyW6JDa/SKFYX99EK1odpkm1SFNdNTFWU0nz/39DI2MTUzNzCwA)

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 229 bytes

```
($RecursionLimit = Infinity; WriteString[$Output, If[Mod[StringLength[a = (If[(a = InputString[]) === EndOfFile, "", StringJoin["\n", a, #0[]]] & )[]], 4] == 1, ToString[#0, InputForm][], If[a == "", "", StringDrop[a, 1]]]]) & []
```

All of the whitespace is for the `InputForm` of the program to match its actual code.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6, 45 bytes

```
$=(_=prompt())=>_.length%4?_:`$=${$};$()`;$()
```

Extension of my 21-byte Bling Quine. Hope that mixing `prompt` and function output is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 33 bytes

```
f=(i,l=i.length)=>l%4?i:("f="+f).repeat(l/4)
```

- **+44** bytes
- **-25%** bonus

Other solutions:

### <s>44</s> 36 bytes

```
f=(i,l=i.length)=>l%4?i:("f="+f).repeat(!!l)
```

```
f=(i,l=i.length)=>l%4?i:l?("f="+f):i
```

### 38.5 bytes

```
f=(i,l=i.length)=>l%4?i:Array(l/4).fill("f="+f).join` `
```

- **+55** bytes
- **-25%** bonus
- **-5%** bonus

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 78 bytes

```sh
s='s=\47%s\47
0()printf $s $s
$[$#1&3]||<<<$1'
0()printf $s $s
$[$#1&3]||<<<$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqJgaGRsYmpmbvG/2Fa92DbGxFy1GEhwGWhoFhRl5pWkKagUAxGXSrSKsqGacWxNjY2NjYqhOiEF//8DAA)

Uses `&3` instead of `%4` so the `%` doesn't get interpreted by `printf`.

The bonus could be added with `repeat $[$#1/4]`  before the `printf` in both places, but unfortunately it gives a higher score (\$ 75\% \times 110 = 82.5 \$).

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 38 - 25% = 28.5 bytes

```
`?DL4%[|[$:q$+$L4/*`?DL4%[|[$:q$+$L4/*
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%3FDL4%25%5B%7C%5B%24%3Aq%24%2B%24L4%2F*%60%3FDL4%25%5B%7C%5B%24%3Aq%24%2B%24L4%2F*&inputs=12345678&header=&footer=)

```
`...`                      # Source code in string
     ?                     # Grab input
      D                    # Triple
       L4%                 # If length is (not) divisible by 4
          [|               # Do nothing, otherwise
            L0>[           # If length is positive
                $          # Swap (to get source-code string)
                 :q$+      # Standard quine - duplicate, uneval, swap, concatenate
                     $     # Swap to get original input
                      L4/  # Length / 4
                         * # (Source code) that many times
```

Trying to get the bonus is sadly longer.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 204 bytes - 30% = 142.8 score

```
=LET(a,LEN(A1),c,CHAR(34),q,"=LET(a,LEN(A1),c,CHAR(34),q,#,IF(MOD(a,4)=0,TRIM(REPT(SUBSTITUTE(q,CHAR(35),c&q&c),a/4)),LEFT(A1,1))) ",IF(MOD(a,4)=0,TRIM(REPT(SUBSTITUTE(q,CHAR(35),c&q&c),a/4)),LEFT(A1,1)))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnDMfSU9R0-k5t3LF?e=fJmfE8)

### 2nd Place, 191 bytes - 25% = 143.25 score

```
=LET(a,LEN(A1),c,CHAR(34),q,"=LET(a,LEN(A1),c,CHAR(34),q,#,IF(MOD(a,4)=0,REPT(SUBSTITUTE(q,CHAR(35),c&q&c),a/4),LEFT(A1,1)))",IF(MOD(a,4)=0,REPT(SUBSTITUTE(q,CHAR(35),c&q&c),a/4),LEFT(A1,1)))
```

### 3rd Place, 179 bytes

```
=LET(a,LEN(A1),c,CHAR(34),q,"=LET(a,LEN(A1),c,CHAR(34),q,#,IF(a*(MOD(a,4)=0),SUBSTITUTE(q,CHAR(35),c&q&c),left(A1,1)))",IF(a*(MOD(a,4)=0),SUBSTITUTE(q,CHAR(35),c&q&c),LEFT(A1,1)))
```

### Best Cheesy Answer, 59 byte - 25% = 44.25 score

```
=LET(a,LEN(A1),IF(MOD(a,4)=0,REPT(FORMULATEXT(B8),a/4),A1))
```