# Cell`s Life #1: Simulate a plant cell

Tags: code-golf, quine

## What am I?

As a plant cell, your program/function/etc. must undergo photosynthesis:
When the input is `6CO2+6H2O+light` in any order, output `C6H12O6+6O2` in any order. It does not have to be the same for each arrangement of the input.

When the input is just `r`, replicate (i.e. output your own code). [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) rules apply.

When input is anything else, output the input (i.e. cat program) (so your cell doesn't expend energy by trying to process useless chemicals)

## Rules without the cell's whole life story

When the input is any of the following:

```
6CO2+6H2O+light
6CO2+light+6H2O
6H2O+6CO2+light
6H2O+light+6CO2
light+6CO2+6H2O
light+6H2O+6CO2
```

Output either `C6H12O6+6O2` or `6O2+C6H12O6`. You do not have to output the same one for each of the 6 inputs.

When the input is just `r`, be a quine (output the source code).

When the input is anything else (or empty), be a cat program (output the input).

Your answer/submission may be a full program, or a function, etc.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/) apply (as always); especially [this.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10033/)

### Python, *ungolfed noncompeting example*

Noncompeting as it breaks quine rules.

```
inp = input()
s = input.split('+') # List of chemicals
a = '6CO2' in s  # Has CO2
b = '6H2O' in s  # Has H2O
c = 'light' in s # Has light
d = len(s) == 3  # Only those 3
output_sugar = a and b and c and d
if output_sugar:
  print('C6H12O6+6O2') # output text
elif inp == 'r':
  print(open(__file__).read()) # quine
else:
  print(inp) # cat program
```

## Scoring

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) - i.e. lowest byte count 'wins'

<sub>(as bigger <s>programs</s> cells will have less surface-to-volume ratio and thus make it harder to intake energy)</sub>

#### <sub>Cell`s Life: S̵̲̿̈́ę̴̬̓r̷͈͑͜i̵̝̔̇ė̴̛̯̹s̶̢͋̓</sub>

<sup>?̶̦͓̰̻̀ ̶̳͇͚̆Ŝ̸̭̤̱̅̔̚t̷̜̩̯̀̿à̶͑͝y̴͚̼͇͊͒̚ ̷̍ͅt̶̮̥̥͌̂ͅủ̵͎n̸͔̉ē̷̊̕d̴̟̭͎͐̈́͝ ̸̗͇̓͗̚?̸̡̗̲͑͛͌</sup>

Comment: This looks like a [Multipart challenge with unrelated sub-tasks](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20905/119296).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quat. Quine + Cat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66276/quat-quine-cat)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, <sup><s>96</s></sup> 87 bytes

```ruby
eval q="$_=%w[6CO2 6H2O light]-$_.split(?+,3)==[]?'C6H12O6+6O2':/^r$/?'eval q=%p'%q:$_"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6BUuzS5Iz83IKlpSVpuhY3w1PLEnMUCm2VVOJtVcujzZz9jRTMPIz8FXIy0zNKYnVV4vWKC3IySzTstXWMNW1to2Pt1Z3NPAyN_M20zfyN1K3044pU9O3VocaoFqirFlqpxCtBjF-mEq9tq6IP4Sy42QIyXhtkvDbYeC4wH8wEi3KBpRCCXAilYFEuBBOiHqEVIl_EVVTEhWaJNlQAJgpxDAA)

The code is an extension of the Ruby quine

```ruby
eval q="$><<'eval q=%p'%q"
```

The optional second argument to `split` is needed to avoid false positives on inputs like `6CO2+6H2O+light+`. The check for an input of `r` uses a [bare regex literal as a conditional](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby#comment496182_5050), saving a byte over the more obvious `$_==?r` but provoking a warning from the interpreter.

Comment: Can `split(?+).sort*?+=='6CO2+6H2O+light'` save some bytes? I'm trying to apply it but it fails

Comment: @AZTECCO That gives a false positive for input `6CO2+6H2O+light+`.

Comment: @AZTECCO It turns out that `split` has an optional extra argument that solves that problem.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for pinging me  @Dingus

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>77</s> 70 bytes

```
“+“6CO2+6H2O+light r“C6H12O6+6O2“ḣ2œṣṢjɗḲi¥@ƭƒ³ị3ị,Ṿ;⁾0ị,⁾vƊƊƲ³ṭƊ”0ịvƊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxxtIDZz9jfSNvMw8tfOyUzPKFEoAoo5m3kYGvmbaZv5GwF5D3csNjo6@eHOxQ93Lso6Of3hjk2Zh5Y6HFt7bNKhzQ93dxsDsc7DnfusHzXuMwCxgXTZsS4g3ASU37n2WNejhrkgCaDg////EVZpg6wGAA)

A full program link taking a string argument and printing a string argument. This currently feels a little verbose for a Jelly answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 98 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
1"D34çýU'rQiXë“6CO26H2O“2ä'‡Žªœ'+ýIåi“C6H12O6+6O2"D34çýU'rQiXë“6CO26H2O“2ä'‡Žªœ'+ýIåi“C6H12O6+6O2
```

Outputs the `C6H12O6+6O2` with two instead of one trailing newlines. Could be fixed in +2 bytes by adding `“` after both `C6H12O6+6O2` in the program.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fUMnF2OTw8sN7Q9WLAjMjDq9@1DDHzNnfyMzDyB/INDq8RP1Rw8Kjew@tOjpZXfvwXs/DSzOB4s5mHoZG/mbaZv5GFBvA9f8/SLF2TmZ6Rok2SC8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
1                   # Push a 1
 "..."              # Push the program's source code
      D             # Duplicate it
       34ç          # Push 34, and convert it to a character with this codepoint: '"'
          ý         # Join the stack with '"'-delimiter
           U        # Pop and store this quine-string in variable `X`
'rQi               '# If the (implicit) input is "r":
    X               #  Push quine-string `X`
                    #  (which is output implicitly with trailing newline)
   ë                # Else:
    “6CO26H2O“      #  Push string "6CO26H2O"
     2ä             #  Push it into two equal-sized parts: ["6CO2","6H2O"]
       '‡Ž         '#  Push dictionary word "light"
          ª         #  Append it to the pair
           œ        #  Get all six permutations of this triplet
            '+ý    '#  Join each inner triplet with "+"-delimiter
    Iåi             #  If the input is in this list:
       “C6H12O6+6O2
                    #   Push string "C6H12O6+6O2\n"
                    #   (which is output implicitly with trailing newline)
                    #  (implicit else)
                    #   (implicitly output the implicit input with trailing newline)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 79 bytes

```javascript
f=x=>x.split`+`.sort().join`+`=='6CO2+6H2O+light'?'6O2+C6H12O6':x=='r'?'f='+f:x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYyxCsMgFEX3/shTpEId3hCwHbJk8xcS0pgaxBdUin9vzdQlZLyHc@42fac0R7fne6D3UqvVRT@LTLt3eRSjTBQz43IjF9rUGrA3SuCgjPBu/WR4ATbQ4/BQBqErTYkNWg3CdqXOFBL5RXpamWXwD8VxBJzfLo0TIR6s/gA)

Nothing special

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>164</s> 142 bytes

```
m=r'm=%r;a=input();print("C6H12O6+6O2"if{"6H2O","6CO2","light"}==set(a.split("+"))else"m=r\x27"+m+"\x27;exec(m%%m)"if a=="r"else a)';exec(m%m)
```

Here is a Python quine that meets all the requirements.

Comment: [This produces the wrong output when the input is `light`.](https://tio.run/##NY1BC4MgHMW/ivwhUozBHLhBeOrSrctu2w4ybBlpYgaN6LM7C3Z7vN97/Nw3dKO93JyP0QifG5H5Ugpt3RwwKZ3XNmCoeH1mDae8YaBbtPZI2wfwmjVQAK9SW8CgP12AVzt6tGMkT5MbdDpTIJsQ693PalPDpBCGZHou7ArUUNhDqRb1xibLDAGCkkEKAR7QMZck/3NDYjw8Pw) Your program is checking whether every part of the input is one of the reactants; the correct condition is the other way around, that every reactant is a part of the input (and also that there is nothing extra).

Comment: Ok, I'll fix that today.

Comment: Byte count has been improved, and the program fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 109 bytes

`=ifs(""=A1,,"6CO2+6H2O+light"=join("+",sort(tocol(split(A1,"+")))),"C6H12O6+6O2","r"=A1,formulatext(F1),1,A1)`

Put the input in cell `A1` and the formula in cell `F1`.

Uses a `cat $0` type quine, so non-competing.